# Can a subclass create a different protocol from parent?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a viewController that implements two delegates, one method from each.

```
@interface scViewController : UIViewController  <TimerDelegate, ManualTimerDelegate>

- (void) updateTimerLabels:(NSString *) sender; //from TimerDelegate
- (void) updateManualTimerLabel:(NSString *) sender;  //from ManualTimerDelegate
```

In the viewController, I set the delegate for both of them to `self`

```
-(Timer *)timer
{
    if (!_timer) {
        _timer = [[Timer alloc] init];
        _timer.delegate = self;
    }

    return _timer;
}
-(ManualTimer *)manualTimer
{
    if (!_manualTimer) {
        _manualTimer = [[ManualTimer alloc] init];
        _manualTimer.delegate = self;
        NSLog(@"%@ ", _manualTimer.delegate);
    }

    return _manualTimer;
}
```

This is how I create the protocols for both Timer class and its subclass ManualTimer

```
@class Timer;

@protocol TimerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)updateTimerLabels:(NSString *)timer;

@end
```

ManualTimer.h

```
#import "Timer.h"

@class ManualTimer;

@protocol ManualTimerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)updateManualTimerLabel:(NSString *)timer;


@end

@interface ManualTimer : Timer
```

Here are the two methods implemented in viewController

```
- (void) updateTimerLabels:(NSString *) sender {
    ....
}

- (void) updateManualTimerLabel:(NSString *) sender {
    ....

}
```

Yet if I try, from a method within ManualTimer class, to call its delegate method on the delegate (i.e. the viewController), xCode tells me that there's no known instance method for it

```
[self.delegate updateManualTimerLabel:self.time];
```

However,  the Timer delegate method works fine, whether I call it from within an instance of Timer, or from within an instance of ManualTimer

```
[self.delegate updateTimerLabels:self.time]; // ok
```

Finally, if I take the method from ManualTimer delegate and declare it in the Timer delegate

```
@protocol TimerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)updateTimerLabels:(NSString *)timer;
-(void)updateManualTimerLabel:(NSString *)timer; //formally in manualTimer
```

Then the xCode error goes away and I can call it from the instance of ManualTimer or Timer.

Question: Can a subclass not create a new protocol, or why is it that the method I declare in the subclass protocol isn't recognized by xCode, but if I declare that same method in the parent protocol that I can call it from either an instance of the parent or the subclass?

While the code works when I put everything in the Timer protocol, it didn't make sense to put a method in there that only relates to a subclass of Timer (i.e. ManualTimer)

Comment: It does appear that xCode doesn't like you to declare a subclass that has its own delegate. Either make them two distinct classes where one doesn't inherit the other or put them in a single class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure to indicate which protocol the delegate conforms to when declaring it?

For example:

```
@interface ManualTimer : Timer
    @property (weak, nonatomic) id<ManualTimerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Comment: That was the problem. I spent about an hour looking at the code before posting and didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define new protocols in a subclass, and add properties that conform to that new protocol.

You need to post the entire header for both Timer and ManualTimer. You don't show the contents of the interface of either class.

It looks like ManualTimer is a subclass of Timer? Correct?

It's awkward that both the class and the subclass have a delegate property, and the 2 delegate properties conform to different protocols. A subclass needs to fully implement all the behavior of it's superclass. So your ManualTimer class's delegate property should probably conform to both the TimerDelegate and ManualTimerDelegate protocols.